# How do I have my bot remove an embed after a certain amount of time?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I need my bot to send an embed and then delete it after a certain amount of time, how would I do this, I can only find thing on how to remove embeds when they are reacted to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `delete` method on the message you sent and give in a object as parameter a property `timeout` which is the number of milliseconds before deleting the message.

Could look like that:

```js
message.send({ embed }).then(newMessage => {
    newMessage.delete({ timeout: 30000 }); // 30 sec after the message will deletes it-self.
});
```

[See Message documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete)

Answer (score 0):

Would a setTimeout() do the trick?

Comment: Probably, but I'm looking for how to delete the embed.